# DOMElement cloning and appending: 'Wrong Document Error'

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

There's something I don't fully understand about node cloning with the PHP's DOM api.  Here's a sample file that quickly duplicates the issue I'm coming across.

```
$doc  = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
$root = $doc->createElement( 'root' ); // This doesn't work either $root = new DOMElement( 'root' );
$doc->appendChild( $root );

$doc2  = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
$root2 = $doc2->createElement( 'root2' );
$doc2->appendChild( $root2 );

// Here comes the error
$root2->appendChild( $root->cloneNode() );
```

When you run this little snippet an exception is thrown

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'DOMException' with message 'Wrong
>   Document Error'

Can I not grab a node from a document, clone it, and then append it to another document?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument->importNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) to import the node into the other document before adding it to the DOM.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.  I was searching through the `DOMNode` and `DOMElement` APIs looking for something that would let me do this and (foolishly) never checked the `DOMDocument` methods =/

Comment: Where did you add importNode? I added it to my code and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @NobleUplift You need to call `importNode` to import a node from one document to another document. After that you can append it as a child where you want.

Comment: I was working on deeply nested tags so I needed to call `$parent->ownerDocument->importNode($child, true)` and then I was able to add it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to append the result of the [`importNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) method to the DOM. Keep in mind that the method could return false when it cannot be imported

```
if ($importedNode = $doc2->importNode($root->cloneNode())) {
    $root2->appendChild($importedNode);
}
```

If you need to import the node, all of it's child nodes (resursively) and/or the node's attributes use the optional second parameter `deep`:

```
if ($importedNode = $doc2->importNode($root->cloneNode(), true)) {
    $root2->appendChild($importedNode);
}
```