# How can I clone nodes between documents in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOMElement cloning and appending: ‘Wrong Document Error’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759137/domelement-cloning-and-appending-wrong-document-error)

I would like to copy all the child nodes of element `foo` in `DOMDocument` A into element `bar` in `DOMDocument` B. However, using [`appendChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/DOMNode.appendChild.php) to do so apparently throws a `DOM_WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR`.

Is there a right way of doing this?

#### XML Document A

```
<foo>
    <child />
    <child />
    <child />
</foo>
```

#### XML Document B

```
<bar>
    <other-child />
    <other-child />
</bar>
```

#### Resulting `DOMDocument`:

```
<bar>
    <other-child />
    <other-child />
    <child />
    <child />
    <child />
</bar>
```

The elements should not be assumed to be empty, but are arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Can you provide some code example?

Comment: On a side note: `DomDocument` & `DOMDocument` are entirely different things in PHP jargon. `DomDocument` was a pre-php5 dom xml implementation: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php Although php4 should be dead, keeping case & thereby version clear when talking about it is advisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to take a look at [DOMDocument::importNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php).

> This function returns a copy of the node to import and associates it with the current document.